# Reassigning adjacency matrix values based on identical comma separated text column

Tags: r

I have data Dat.1 that has a comma separated text column c.2 that looks like

```
c.1     c.2
A       IN, CA, IL, NY
B       NJ, IN,AR
C       DC, NY
D       TX, AR, IN
```

I use c.1 to create an empty adjacency matrix Aij

```
    A   B   C   D
A   0   0   0   0
B   0   0   0   0   
C   0   0   0   0
D   0   0   0   0
```

I want to search for the similar text in the comma separated column, c.2 to reassign my adjacency matrix Aij with 1 if the comma separated text is identical. For example, in Dat.1 “IN” is present in A, B and D of column c.1 and I will reassign AB, AD in Aij with 1. Similarly “NY” is in A, and C and I will assign another AC=1. “AR” is in B and D and I will assign BD=1. I will then add the values and my new matrix will look like,

```
    A   B   C   D
A   0   1   1   1
B   1   0   0   1   
C   1   0   0   0
D   1   1   0   0
```

How do I read the common text and reassign my adjacency matrix without separating the column c.2 into many sub-columns?

Comment: Shouldn't (A, C) be 1 not 2 (only NY is in common), and (B,D) = 2 (IN and AR in common)? And shouldn't your matrix be symmetric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have to separate `c.2` at some point, so you can compare the values. Otherwise you can try do some regex tricks but I doubt that'll be faster, and then you have to worry about escaping your text to be regex-safe.

I'm sure there are many ways to do this (there may be some inbuilt packages with faster methods encoded), but the key to this solution is base R's `combn` function.

```
# recreate your dataframe
x <- data.frame(c.1=LETTERS[1:4],
                c.2=c('IN, CA, IL, NY', 'NJ, IN,AR', 'DC, NY', 'TX, AR, IN'),
                stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Here we split up the c2 column into a list rather than a dataframe, since the number of entries in each row is not the same

```
# split up the comma values
bits <- strsplit(x$c.2, ', ?')
```

Constuct a matrix of 0s to hold your adjacency matrix:

```
adj <- matrix(0, nrow=nrow(x), ncol=nrow(x), dimnames=list(x$c.1, x$c.1))
```

First, realise that your adjacency matrix is symmetric, i.e. if (B and A) has 1 element in common, so does (A and B). So we only need to calculate the number of common components for the upper or lower half of the matrix, and then can mirror it.

The key is `combn(1:4, m=2, FUNCTION)`. First try `combn(1:4, m=2)` and you will see it makes a matrix of combinations of the numbers 1:4, i.e. a matrix with all coordinates into the adjacency matrix (excluding the diagonal). You could instead do something like `expand.grid(1:4, 1:4)` but this will include **permutations** of length 2 from 1:4, i.e. it'll include both (row 1, column 3) and (row 3, column 1) which we have previously determined will have the same value anyway. So we use `combn` to only generate coordinates into the upper (or lower) half of the adjacency matrix.

Then for `FUN` we simply see how many elements in column A are in column B by using `intersect` on `bits`.

Finally we use `adj[lower.tri(adj, diag=F)]` to assign the values to the lower half of the adjacency matrix (`<-` assigns by-column and our coordinates are by-row so we use the lower half not the upper half to assign to):

```
adj[lower.tri(adj, diag=F)] <-
  combn(1:nrow(x), m=2, function (coords) {
    length(intersect(bits[[coords[1]]], bits[[coords[2]]]))
  })
```

And then finally we fill in the upper half of the matrix using the lower half values (the `t(adj)` is some fancy footing because of assigning by-column, again).

```
adj[upper.tri(adj)] <- t(adj)[upper.tri(adj)]
> adj
  A B C D
A 0 1 1 1
B 1 0 0 2
C 1 0 0 0
D 1 2 0 0
```

It's a long answer beacuse of all the explanation, but really it's just 3 lines:

```
adj <- matrix(0, nrow=nrow(x), ncol=nrow(x), dimnames=list(x$c.1, x$c.1)
adj[lower.tri(adj, diag=F)] <-
  combn(1:nrow(x), m=2, function (coords) {
    length(intersect(bits[[coords[1]]], bits[[coords[2]]]))
  })
adj[upper.tri(adj)] <- t(adj)[upper.tri(adj)]
```